# Control over UIViewController interfaceorientation

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a new `UIViewController` like below,

```
@implementation ParentViewController

- (id)init
{
   // some stuff
}

- (BOOL)CreateChildViewController
{
   UIViewController *childVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
}

@end
```

Now i need to stop interfaceOrientation of childVC.

Is it possible, if so how??

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

to any view controller to determine auto rotate behaviour.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> By default, this method returns YES for the UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait orientation only. If your view controller supports additional orientations, override this method and return YES for all orientations it supports.

In short, if you subclass `UIViewController` and only want to support portrait, you don't need to do anything.  Otherwise you will need to add this method and decide whether to allow rotation to another orientation.

Read the section titled "Handling View Rotations".